# Count number of repeats in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I tried to solve one problem but without success.

I have two list of number

```
{1,2,3,4}
{5,6,7,8,9}
```

And I have table

```
ID     Number
1        1
1        2
1        7
1        2
1        6
2        8 
2        7
2        3
2        9
```

Now I need to count how many times number from second list come after number from first list but I should count only one by one id

in example table above result should be 2

three matched pars but because we have only two different IDs result is 2 instead 3

Pars:

```
1     2
1     7
```

---

```
1     2
1     6
```

---

```
2     3
2     9
```

note. I work with MSSQL

Edit. There is one more column Date which determined order

Edit2 - Solution

i write this  query

```
SELECT * FROM table t
left JOIN table tt ON tt.ID = t.ID 
    AND tt.Date > t.Date 
    AND t.Number IN (1,2,3,4) 
    AND tt.Number IN (6,7,8,9)
```

And after this I had a plan to group by id and use only one match for each id but execution take a lot time

Comment: What determines "after"? I don't see any column that would determine ordering for the data.

Comment: There is one more column Date which determined order

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: @HABO I update question with my code/idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a query that would do it:

```
select     a.id, min(a.number) as a, min(b.number) as b
from       mytable a
inner join mytable b
        on a.id = b.id
       and a.date < b.date
       and b.number in (5,6,7,8,9)
where      a.number in (1,2,3,4)
group by   a.id
```

Output is:

```
id  a   b
1   1   6
2   3   9
```

So the two pairs are output each on one line, with the value **a** belonging to the first group of numbers, and the value of column **b** to the second group.

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4dd69/1)

#### Comments on attempt (edit 2 to question)

Later you added a query attempt to your question. Some comments about that attempt:

- You don't need a `left join` because you really want to have a match for both values. `inner join` has in general better performance, so use that.
- The condition `t.Number IN (1,2,3,4)` does not belong in the `on` clause. In combination with a `left join` the result will include `t` records that violate this condition. It should be put in the `where` clause.
- Your concern about performance may be warranted, but can be resolved by adding a useful index on your table, i.e. on `(id, number, date)` or `(id, date, number)`

Comment: Thanks, this is similar solution like mine and it have same problem. After 5 minutes of executing query I still haven't result. and for one year time period it take 3 minutes

Comment: Did you see my last bullet point? (Add the index and see what performance is then). Also, are the two groups of numbers dynamic? By what are they determined? I would use an indexed table for that, and your performance will be better again.

Comment: I sow your update after my comment above. Table in question is generated from previous query. I going to create temp table and set index on it and delete it after executing main query. Thanks for help !!